# How to run AWS lambda every 6 hours?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have a lambda which I know works.

I would like to set it to run every six hours.

What is the simplest way of making this happen

#### Note

This is not something I will need to do regularly, so I am happy to do it through the browser (although cli is also good)

Comment: AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Comment: @stannius thanks. I came across that googling. It basically says that scheduling a lambda is possible. It links to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)but I still don’t know where I need to go and what exactly I need to do in order to make the lambda run every six hours

Comment: I'm still not quite there, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mxq8yuc1doY) video is very useful

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will trigger your lambda function (with that JSON input, if applied) every 6 hours from the scheduled time.

[image]

**Step 1:** Go to `Amazon EventBridge` service

**Step 2:** Click on `Rules` on the left panel and click `Create Rule` button

**Step 3:** Enter a `Name` for the rule and optionally enter a description

**Step 4:** Select `Schedule` and click `Next`

**Step 5:** Select `A schedule that runs at a regular rate...` for Schedule Pattern and

- Enter `6` for `Value`
- Select `Hours` for `Unit`.

**Step 6:** Select `AWS Service` for `Target Types` and select `Lambda function` from list of targets.

**Step 7:** Select the appropriate Lambda function. Optionally, you can send a specific JSON value when this lambda function is trigger by clicking on the `Additional settings` and selecting `Constant (JSON text)`.

**Step 8:** Click `Next`, add Tags optionally, review the rule, and click `Create rule`.

---

Note: If you would like to trigger at a specific time every 6 hours (e.g. 12am, 6am, 12pm, etc.), you have to select `A fine-grained schedule that runs at a specific time` in **Step 5**.

This is the expression you would need to use:

- Minutes: `*`
- Hours: `0/6`
- Day of month: `?`
- Month: `*`
- Day of week: `*`
- Year: `*`

Comment: Rules now exist elsewhere under a service called AWS EventBridge

Comment: @gavxn thanks, I've updated my answer so steps and screenshot reflects EventBridge now.